# Codeigniter, how do i get 2 params in the controller using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hey guys i got a shopping cart that loads using jquery, now im using codeigniter, and i dont know how to get two of the params i use by get. This's the javascritp method that calls the script.

```
  function anade() {
      var idnumero = $(this).val();
      var quant = $("#num" + idnumero).val();
      $("#carrito").load("http://example.com/cart/addToCart?p=" + $(this).val() + "&cant=" + quant);
  }
```

this is my old script, now im implementing mvc with codeigniter, so i wont to re write this:

```
session_start();
$suma=0;
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $_SESSION['product'][$_SESSION['count']] = $_GET['p'];
    $_SESSION['quantity'][$_SESSION['count']] = $_GET['quant'];
    $_SESSION['count']++;
}

$conexion = mysqli_connect($bd_servidor, $bd_usuario, $bd_contrasenia, $bd_basededatos);
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf-8");

echo"<table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $_SESSION['count']; $i++) {
    //echo "Product:  " . $_SESSION['product'][$i] . "<br />";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE idproducto=" . $_SESSION['producto'][$i] . "";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        echo "<tr><td>Unid : ".$_SESSION['quantity'][$i]."</td><td>" . $fila['name'] . "</td><td> " . number_format(($_SESSION['quantity'][$i]*$fila['price']),2) . "</td></tr>";
        $suma+= $_SESSION['quantity'][$i]*$fila['price'] ;
    }
}
//echo"<hr>";
echo "<tr><td>Subtotal</td><td></td><td>".  number_format($suma,2)."</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

i would like to know how should i do the controller. something like this is OK?
function getCart($p, $cant){
      method...}

Thxs!

Comment: That would work if you configure query strings properly.

Comment: where is the html markup and the PHP?

Comment: there it is the old php script

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you should use for 2 parameters to get in CodeIgniter.

**Java Script**

```
function anade() {
      var idnumero = $(this).val();
      var quant = $("#num" + idnumero).val();
      $("#carrito").load("http://example.com/cart/addToCart/" + $(this).val() + "/" + quant);
  }
```

**In CodeIgniter**

```
function getCart($p, $cant)
{
}
```

Comment: Alternately, you can keep your Javascript code as it is and change in CodeIgniter function by removing parameters and get them through simple $_GET or like  $p = $this->input->get("p");